# Conjunction of Moon and Rahu in all birth charts

Tags: scripture, astrology, birth, rahu, moon

I heard from several sources that moon and Rahu are enemies.

Is it true in astrology in general?

If yes, what can be the consequences if a person has conjunction of Moon and Rahu in the three birth charts, namely, Lagna, Navamsa, Chandra?

If there are many sub-cases, such as room number in which they present, then which scripture deals with their conjunction in detail?